# problem with find an element using cypress and xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, find, cypress, element

I'm trying write a code (using cypress) to bypass long press verification such that
[verification image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tOks.jpg)

this is inspect>> id and class values are changes every session
`<p id="oVzBRZgfQmDATFj" class="NMBmfXVZnqeiNEY" style="animation: 111.8ms ease 0s 1 normal none running textColorIReverse;">Press &amp; Hold</p>`

I was tried XPath Selectors and i get the following:
//p[text()='Press & Hold']

//p[starts-with(text(),'Press & Hold')]

//p[position()=1]

//p[normalize-space()='Press & Hold']

//p[last()]

//p[contains(text(),'Press & Hold')]

//p[contains(normalize-space(),'Press & Hold')]

//p[.='Press & Hold']

After experiment each of them such as element:

```
cy.xpath('//p[starts-with(text(),"Press & Hold")]').trigger('mousedown')
cy.wait(10000)
cy.xpath('//p[starts-with(text(),"Press & Hold")]').trigger('mouseup')
```

This error appears:
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: //p[starts-with(text(),"Press & Hold")], but never found it.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bhaA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to modifying selectors in the app, an easier approach would be to use `.contains()`.

Assuming your `<p>` contains the events needed to verify, you can simply get the jquery element with the following:

```js
cy.contains('p', 'Press & Hold')
```

I'm not sure if the verification process requires the user to be holding the click for 10 seconds, but i'm sure you can do less time.

If the `.trigger()` is not verifying, which could be guarded against, you can try using [`.realClick()`](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#cyrealclick) from the [`cypress-real-events`](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) plugin.

Comment: Logically the solutions are correct but I found out that the error is because the captcha page link is different from the login link. I mean the link becomes different after the login process. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you redirected to another baseUrl when you get to the press and hold verification step?

Comment: After the first test case (login url) and put email and password was done, I'm redirected to capatcha with another url, and inside it contains 'hold and press'

Comment: You may have to use a combination of `.origin()` along with other commands to get pass this.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have used succeeds in a simple test.

Using the following in a simple (isolated) test works

```html
<p>Press &amp; Hold</p>
```

```js
cy.xpath('//p[starts-with(text(),"Press & Hold")]')
    .trigger('mousedown')  
...
})
```

---

**Testing with redirect to new origin**

```js
cy.origin('redirect-url-after-login', () => {

  cy.xpath('//p[starts-with(text(),"Press & Hold")]')
    .trigger('mousedown')  
  cy.wait(10000)
  cy.xpath('//p[starts-with(text(),"Press & Hold")]')
    .trigger('mouseup')

})
```

You must turn on this experimental feature in Cypress config

```js
// cypress.json

{
  ...
  "experimentalSessionAndOrigin": true
}
```

Comment: Logically the solutions are correct but I found out that the error is because the captcha page link is different from the login link. I mean the link becomes different after the login process.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, can you add any details? The screenshots you provided don't give any clue about what links are where. I assume the button you wish to press and hold is inside the captcha mechanism, but what has the "login link" to do with it and where is it?

Comment: After the first test case (login url) and put email and password was done, I'm redirected to capatcha with another url, and inside it contains 'hold and press'

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you mean there is a "different origin" problem. If so, take a look at this page [origin#Usage](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Usage). You execute the code above inside the callback of `cy.orgin()` and specify the URL of the redirect as first parameter.

Comment: TypeError
cy.xpath is not a function

  15 |     cy.wait(1000)
  16 |     cy.get('.page-title').should('contain','Please verify you are a human')
> 17 |     cy.origin('redirect-url-after-login', () => {
     |        ^
  18 |         cy.xpath('//p[starts-with(text(),"Press & Hold")]').trigger('mousedown')  
  19 |         cy.wait(10000)
  20 |         cy.xpath('//p[starts-with(text(),"Press & Hold")]').trigger('mouseup')

Comment: ***TypeError cy.xpath is not a function*** did you add the `cypress-xpath` library? I assumed so, since you have `cy.xpath` in your question.

Comment: Yes I did, but not working.

Comment: You also need to `require` it in the test or in support.

Comment: If `cy.xpath()` was working before, there is no reason for it not to work inside `cy.origin()`. Sounds like a typo somewhere.

Comment: By the way, you will need to give `cy.origin` a valid url. You just pasted the string I gave as a hint, which obviously will not work for you.